Simple linear regression converge to wrong shape
Learning PyTorch. Trying to write a simple linear regression myself.

Red: training set
Blue: test set
orange: prediction after each iteration
yellow: prediction after last batch

seems like orange dots try to pass the center of the red dots. The slope however doesn't converge. Tried to change learning rate, increase epochs, change random initializations, or using L1 loss (abs). Tried to ask chatGPT 4o, but it hallucinates.
Feels like prisoner's dilemma between a and b. a has to increase while b decreases at the same time. Is this local minimum? How to jump out of it? Any thoughts / links to resources or forums?

import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = torch.linspace(2, 5, 50)
y = X * 3 - 10 + torch.rand(50)

X_train, X_test = X[:30], X[30:]
y_train, y_test = y[:30], y[30:]
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color="red")
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color="blue")

torch.manual_seed(43)
a = torch.tensor(6., requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor(-20., requires_grad=True)

for i in range(10):
    loss = (a * X_train + b - y_train).pow(2).mean()
    print(loss, a, b)
    y_predict = a * X + b
    plt.scatter(X, y_predict.detach(), color="orange")

    loss.backward()
    # break
    with torch.no_grad():
        a -= .03 * a.grad
        b -= .01 * b.grad
    a.grad.zero_()
    b.grad.zero_()

loss = (a * X_train + b - y_train).abs().mean()
display("loss", loss)

y_predict = a * X_test + b
plt.scatter(X_test, y_predict.detach(), color="yellow")


You're only taking 10 steps, have you tried more? Track the loss function over each iteration and see if it has stopped decreasing. Have you tried changing the learning rates (0.03 and 0.01 for simple linear model seem too small to me)?

Plugged this into an editor and played with it. Increasing the steps from 10 to 1000 and increasing the learning rate to 0.1 for both a and b leads to a=3.16 b=-9.95 which is a lot closer to the expected 3 and -10 that you used to generate the test data.

@jodag Wow! I previously bumped it to 100 epochs and couldn't see much effect. Didn't expect it to actually require 1000 epochs. It worked now. Guess I was more greedy than my code. This is interesting. Thanks!!
